# Keep transition in effect after hover

Tags: html, css

When i hover over the words "Skate Night" a list will show up with a transition, but i can't get the list to stay when i move my mouse off the text.

This is what i've tried.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta name="description" content="Skate Night is a community website by skaters, for skaters where you can share your content, get to know other skaters and enjoy what people have to share." />
  <title>
   Skate Night
  </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
 </head>
<body>
<div id="header"><a id="sn" href="home.html">Skate Night</a>
<a class="menu" href="forums.html"><li>Forums</li></a>
<a class="menu" href="videos.html"><li>Videos</li></a>
<a class="menu" href="about.html"><li>About</li></a>
<a class="menu" href="team.html"><li>Join the team</li></a>
<a class="menu" href="login.html"><li>Login</li></a>
</div>
</body>
</html>

html
{
background-color: #ff4444;
}

#header
{
background-color: #000000;
height: 20%;
margin-left: -1%;
margin-top: -1%;
padding-top: 3%;
width: 101.6%;
box-shadow: 5px 10px 30px #009900;
display: inline-block;
}

#sn
{
margin-left: 1%;
margin-bottom: -1%;
color: #e0e0e0;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 400%;
box-shadow: 5px 10px 30px #009900;
border-radius: 10px;
transition: all 0.5s;
transition-delay:all 9999999s;
}

#sn:hover
{
color: #009900;
box-shadow: 5px 10px 30px #e0e0e0;
}

.menu
{
display: inline-block;
color: #000000;
padding-left: 5%;
transition: all 0.5s;
text-decoration: none;
list-style: none;
}

#sn:hover ~ .menu
{
transition-delay:all 0s;
font-size: 200%;
color: #009900;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think you will be able to get a solution for this with just html or css, you will need javascript

Comment: If you're talking about document.getElementById for the js solution then the transitions will not work

Answer (score 0):

You need JavaScript (JS) for that

```js
function snActive () {
  this.classList.add("active")
}
var sn = document.querySelector("#sn");
sn.addEventListener("mouseenter",snActive,false)
```

```css
html
{
background-color: #ff4444;
}

#header
{
background-color: #000000;
height: 20%;
margin-left: -1%;
margin-top: -1%;
padding-top: 3%;
width: 101.6%;
box-shadow: 5px 10px 30px #009900;
display: inline-block;
}

#sn
{
margin-left: 1%;
margin-bottom: -1%;
color: #e0e0e0;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 400%;
box-shadow: 5px 10px 30px #009900;
border-radius: 10px;
transition: all 0.5s;
transition-delay:all 9999999s;
}

#sn:hover
{
color: #009900;
box-shadow: 5px 10px 30px #e0e0e0;
}

.menu
{
display: inline-block;
color: #000000;
padding-left: 5%;
transition: all 0.5s;
text-decoration: none;
list-style: none;
}

#sn.active ~ .menu
{
transition-delay:all 0s;
font-size: 200%;
color: #009900;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <meta name="description" content="Skate Night is a community website by skaters, for skaters where you can share your content, get to know other skaters and enjoy what people have to share." />
  <title>
   Skate Night
  </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
 </head>
<body>
<div id="header"><a id="sn" href="home.html">Skate Night</a>
<a class="menu" href="forums.html"><li>Forums</li></a>
<a class="menu" href="videos.html"><li>Videos</li></a>
<a class="menu" href="about.html"><li>About</li></a>
<a class="menu" href="team.html"><li>Join the team</li></a>
<a class="menu" href="login.html"><li>Login</li></a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do i apply the js? onmouseover for sn?

Comment: @Provision `"mouseover"` or `"mouseenter"` .

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with pure css:

```
#header:hover #sn
{
color: #009900;
box-shadow: 5px 10px 30px #e0e0e0;
}
```

Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/hprnxw8n/

Answer (score 0):

here it is with css, added a new div. you need to put li tags in a ul or ol.

EDITED my answer, took li's out altogether as they weren't doing anything, I thought they were for styling but they weren't

```css
{
background-color: #ff4444;
}

#header
{
background-color: #000000;
height: 20%;
margin-left: -1%;
margin-top: -1%;
padding-top: 3%;
width: 101.6%;
box-shadow: 5px 10px 30px #009900;
display: inline-block;
}

#sn
{
margin-left: 1%;
margin-bottom: -1%;
color: #e0e0e0;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 400%;
box-shadow: 5px 10px 30px #009900;
border-radius: 10px;
transition: all 0.5s;
transition-delay:all 9999999s;
}

#sn:hover
{
color: #009900;
box-shadow: 5px 10px 30px #e0e0e0;
}

.menu
{
display: inline-block;
color: #000000;
padding-left: 5%;
transition: all 0.5s;
text-decoration: none;
list-style: none;
}

#sn:hover ~ #submenu a
{
transition-delay:all 0s;
font-size: 200%;
color: #009900;
} 
#submenu:hover .menu
{transition-delay:all 0s;
font-size: 200%;
color: #009900;
  }
```

```html
<div id="header"><a id="sn" href="home.html">Skate Night</a>
 <div id="submenu" >
<a class="menu" href="forums.html">Forums</a>
<a class="menu" href="videos.html">Videos</a>
<a class="menu" href="about.html">About</a>
<a class="menu" href="team.html">Join the team</a>
<a class="menu" href="login.html">Login</a>
</div></div>
```

Comment: worked in the snippet earlier, try now , I've taken li's out altogether. it's probably you putting the ul in that busted it

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems that I will attempt to solve here using only CSS and a bit of HTML restructuring. First of all, you list items are not inside a list - this in and of itself is already semantically incorrect and will cause issues. Heres the HTML I would use:

```
<div id="header">
<a id="sn" href="home.html">Skate Night</a>
<ul>
    <li><a  href="forums.html">Forums</a></li>
    <li><a href="videos.html">Videos</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="team.html">Join the team</a></li>
    <li><a href="login.html">Login</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I have nested your links *inside* the list items and added them to a list itself. This allows for accurate targeting so I can remove you class of `.menu`. I will already preface this by saying that I havent replicated your styling entirely here as that isn't the purpose of this answer. The purpose is to show how two elements can interact like that, the styling is but a detail.

Now, theres the problem that I can't really see what your animation is trying to do at all. You can, however, be clever about it. If you want a persistent animation, you can apply it to both your header and your list. So lets try that:

```
html {
  background-color: #ff4444;
}

#header{
    background-color: #000000;
    height: 20%;
    margin-left: -1%;
    margin-top: -1%;
    padding-top: 3%;
    width: 101.6%;
    box-shadow: 5px 10px 30px #009900;
    display: inline-block;
}

#sn{
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-bottom: -1%;
    color: #e0e0e0;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 400%;
    box-shadow: 5px 10px 30px #009900;
    border-radius: 10px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    transition-delay:all 9999999s;
}

/* Here I added some styling for you new list */
#header ul {
    display: inline-block;
}
#header ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000000;
    padding-left: 5%;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    text-decoration: none;
    /* The below is important to prevent hovers on the ul */
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0;
}
#header ul li a {
    color: inherit;
}
/* Here is where the magic happens */
#header #sn:hover {
    color: #009900;
    box-shadow: 5px 10px 30px #e0e0e0;
}
#header #sn:hover + ul li,
#header ul:hover li {
    color: #009900;
}
```

As long as you insure (by using paddings, for example) that you cursor does not fall in a gap between there `#sn` and the `ul`, then the hover will apply to both and stay applied until you leave either the `#sn` or the `ul`. You need to use a `height: 0` and `overflow: hidden` to prevent hovers from happening *before* you hover on your `#sn` but otherwise this is the way to do it without javascript.

```css
html {
  background-color: #ff4444;
}

#header{
  background-color: #000000;
  height: 20%;
  margin-left: -1%;
  margin-top: -1%;
  padding-top: 3%;
  width: 101.6%;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px 30px #009900;
  display: inline-block;
}

#sn{
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-bottom: -1%;
  color: #e0e0e0;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 400%;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px 30px #009900;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  transition-delay:all 9999999s;
}

#header ul {
 display: inline-block;
}
#header ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 color: #000000;
 padding-left: 5%;
 transition: color 0.5s;
 text-decoration: none;
 list-style: none;
 overflow: hidden;
 height: 0;
}
#header ul li a {
 color: inherit;
}


#header #sn:hover {
color: #009900;
box-shadow: 5px 10px 30px #e0e0e0;
}
#header #sn:hover + ul li,
#header ul:hover li {
 color: #009900;
 height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
<a id="sn" href="home.html">Skate Night</a>
<ul>
 <li><a  href="forums.html">Forums</a></li>
 <li><a href="videos.html">Videos</a></li>
 <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
 <li><a href="team.html">Join the team</a></li>
 <li><a href="login.html">Login</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```